# pulling data using memcache from mysql

Tags: php, memcached

I've been trying to use Memcache to reduce the executions to the mysql server.
I've looked through several tutorials and cannot figure out why the following code returns false. Could someone please help/explain why this is not returning true. I think that the data from the sql is not getting into the memcache, but I can't find how to correctly implement it. It works on a straight connection to the sql server.
I've edited the code to based of that example, but it still returns false.

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 20069) or die('Error in Connection!');


$connect = new mysqli("...", "...", "...", "...");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();}

$sort = md5("SELECT * FROM CarpetStyles where Manufacturer = 'Blossom'");

function database_result($sort, $expire = 60) {
   $memcached_key = 'db:' . $sort;
     $cached = $memcached->get($memcached_key);
   if ($memcached->getResultCode() !== Memcached::RES_NOTFOUND)
     {return $cached;}

$result_array = $result->fetchAll();
    $memcached->set($memcached_key, $result_array, $expire);
    return $result_array;
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that retrieves the data from the database and stores it in memcache?

Comment: That's probably the issue. I'm completely new and can't figure out how to put the data from the database into the memcache. I've not found an example to show me how.

Comment: Some simple searches show - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124454/memcache-storing-mysql-results